# How to define data type in mySql stored procedure to accept list of object as an in parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 'one to many' relationship in two tables. In that case I want to write a store procedured in mySql which can accept the list of child table object and update the tables. The challenge I am facing is what will be the data type of the in parameter for list of object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `VARCHAR(65535)` in MySQL.

Comment: We can run the loop in Stored Procedure using Varchar(max)??

Comment: @deepeshkumar:- Yes you can!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `list` data type in MySQL.

Given the info that you are coming from Oracle DB, you might wanna know that MySQL does not have a strict concept of objects. And, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10266101/2869791), unfortunately, you cannot create a custom data type on your own.

The way to work around it is to imagine a `table` as a `class`. Thus, your objects will become records of the said table.

You have to settle for one of the following approaches:

- Concatenated IDs: Store the concatenated IDs you want to operate on in a string equivalent datatype- like `VARCHAR(5000)` or `TEXT`. This way you can either split and loop over the string or compose a prepared statement dynamically and execute it.
- Use a temporary table: Fetch the child table objects, on the fly, into the temporary table and process them. This way, once you create the temporary table with the fields & constraints that you like, you can use
  `SELECT ... INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE_NAME` to populate the table accordingly. The `SELECT` statement should fetch the properties you need.

Depending on the size of the data, you might want to choose the temp table approach for larger data sets.

Comment: Thanks, how we will extract the values from the properties laying inside the object?

Comment: We can't create a new data type in Mysql? I did the same thing in Oracle DB. Now facing challenge with Mysql db.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Text** data type for store large amount of data in single variable

you can define in sp as:

```
In Variable_name TEXT
```