# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near TYPE AS ENUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running into this strange error. Everything in the code in my eyes seems fine to me.
I was looking at the SQL docs but i couldn't find anything.
Could it be because i'm running a really old SQL server version? (MySQL Server 5.5)
It has always been my go to thing and I've never had any errors like that.

```
-- Create a table for the user's settings
CREATE TYPE currency AS ENUM ('oldscape', 'newscape');
CREATE TYPE visibility AS ENUM ('public', 'private');
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    user_id bigint,
    currency_setting currency DEFAULT null,
    visibility visibility DEFAULT 'public',
    client_seed text DEFAULT null,
    oldscape bigint DEFAULT 0,
    newscape bigint DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)    
);


CREATE TABLE dice (
    user_id bigint,
    nonce int DEFAULT -1,
    server_seed char(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);


CREATE TABLE commands_run (
    user_id bigint,
    guild_id bigint,
    command_name varchar(20),
    count integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, guild_id, command_name)
);


CREATE TABLE command_log (
    id serial,
    user_id bigint,
    message_id bigint,
    guild_id bigint,
    command_name varchar(20),
    message_text text,
    time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
);


CREATE TABLE modification_log (
    id serial,
    cashier_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    message_id bigint,
    oldscape_mod bigint,
    newscape_mod bigint,
    reason varchar(256),
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id, user_id)
);


CREATE TABLE house_modification_log (
    id serial,
    message_id bigint,
    oldscape_mod bigint,
    newscape_mod bigint,
    reason varchar(256),
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
);


CREATE TABLE tickets (
    user_id bigint,
    ticket_count integer,
    day integer DEFAULT null,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, day)
);
```

Would love some insight on what is wrong or what i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create type? Where does it say you can do this in mysql? and you seem to be confusing sqlserver and mysql 'Could it be because i'm running a really old SQL server version? (MySQL Server 5.5) '

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266101/create-type-on-mysql

Comment: *I was looking at the SQL docs but i couldn't find anything.* You must NOT use the construction which was not found in the documentation.

Comment: I'm currently looking at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462497/creating-enum-variable-type-in-mysql

Comment: And did you read the _answer_ to the question you linked to?

Comment: Yes i did. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the ENUM type was introduced in MySQL 5.6

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek, What makes you say that? ENUM has been supported since early versions of MySQL. But `CREATE TYPE` of anything is not supported by any version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If its acceptbale to you, why not declare the first table like this and fix your issue:

-- Create a table for the user's settings

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    user_id bigint,
    currency_setting ENUM ('oldscape', 'newscape')  DEFAULT null,
    visibility ENUM ('public', 'private') DEFAULT 'public',
    client_seed text DEFAULT null,
    oldscape bigint DEFAULT 0,
    newscape bigint DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)    
);
```