# reuse enum type in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

There are two tables `University` and `School`.

- `University` has an enum type primary key `university_name` (this is fine, it will be rarely modified).
- Another table `School` needs to have this `university_name` column.

How can it do it without re-defining enum values?

```
University[Enum university_name(A,B,C)*,DateTime created]

School[String school name,int id,Enum university_name(A,B,C)]
```

If this isn't possible in Mysql, how are such cases usually covered?

String column in school with foreign key as enum `University->university_name` isn't allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ENUM variable type in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462497/creating-enum-variable-type-in-mysql)