# What is wrong with the below ENUM (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, create-table

I have to create test table for the course and face an issue with ENUM below:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Lname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
Fname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
Gender ENUM(‘M’, ’F’),
Specialty ENUM(‘1’, ’2’, ’3’, ’4’),
Grade ENUM (‘I’, ’J’, ’M’, ’S’),
Start_date date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And it does not work - I get:
"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘M’, ’F’),
Specialty ENUM(‘1’, ’2’, ’3’, ’4’),
Grade ENU' at line 5"

Whenever I try to create without ENUM fields - everything is fine. If I try to ALTER TABLE with those ENUMs again - it fails.

What is wrong there?

Comment: MySQL does not understand curly quotes.  I suspect that is your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ENUM variable type in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462497/creating-enum-variable-type-in-mysql)

Comment: You use the wrong quote `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below query use `'` this quote insteated of `

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people_tes ( 
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Lname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
Fname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
Gender ENUM('M', 'F'), 
Specialty ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4'), 
Grade ENUM ('I', 'J', 'M', 'S'), 
Start_date date DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Somehow on https://www.w3schools.com/ on Try SQL the statements with usual '' from the keyboard worked fine.